# Pass all lines in a file as single space separated argument

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, arguments

I have a txt file:

`txt1
txt2
txt3`

I want to pass all these lines as a single space separated argument:
`myProgram -a txt1 txt2 txt3`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, should have searched more thoroughly.

`mapfile -t <arguments.txt
myProgram -a "${MAPFILE[@]}"`